# Load data from a comp3 file to informatica

Tags: cobol, informatica, codepages

I have a Comp3 file as a source in my mapping. How do I load data in the target.
The source defination has fixed length and the Code Page is '7-bit ASCII'.
The data is not populated properly. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear whether the source is in ASCII or you need the data in ASCII.

Either way, any non-text field is not a good way to pass data between ASCII/EBCDIC in either direction. Binary, packed-decimal and floating-point fields are neither ASCII nor EBCDIC, which are codes for representing bytes. So if going through a translation binary/packed-decimal/floating-point will be garbled (you can get lucky with a limited range of binary values).

The professional way is to only give textual data when transferring between systems, so that standard translations can be used. The sloppy way is to give binary/packed-decimal/floating-point and let the other party sort out the mess. This sloppy way should never get through any computer audit, nor satisfy regulatory requirements, other compliance issues of leave your accountant feeling happy.

You are the other party. **You** tell **them** to give you textual data. Problem gone.